# Component is receiving props from another component as well is connected to the store to call the action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

So, as the title suggests, Cards component is receiving props from UserPosts, as well as it's connected to the store to dispatch an action. But it looks like this is not working at all. Connecting a component is not working for me. Maybe I am missing something? Can someone show me the correct way to do it. I'm trying to delete a post on clicking on the delete button.
Here is the code.

`UserPosts`

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { getUserPosts, getCurrentUser } from "../actions/userActions"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import Cards from "./Cards"

class UserFeed extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken")
    if (authToken) {
      this.props.dispatch(getCurrentUser(authToken))
      if (this.props && this.props.userId) {
        this.props.dispatch(getUserPosts(this.props.userId))
      } else {
        return null
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { isFetchingUserPosts, userPosts } = this.props
    return isFetchingUserPosts ? (
      <p>Fetching....</p>
    ) : (
      <div>
        {userPosts &&
          userPosts.map(post => {
            return <Cards key={post._id} post={post} />
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToPros = state => {
  return {
    isFetchingUserPosts: state.userPosts.isFetchingUserPosts,
    userPosts: state.userPosts.userPosts,
    userId: state.auth.user._id
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToPros)(UserFeed)
```

`Cards`

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { deletePost } from "../actions/userActions"

class Cards extends Component {
  handleDelete = postId => {
    this.props.dispatch(deletePost(postId))
  }

  render() {
    const { _id, title, description } = this.props.post
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-content">
          <div className="media">
            <div className="media-left">
              <figure className="image is-48x48">
                <img
                  src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png"
                  alt="Placeholder image"
                />
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div className="media-content" style={{ border: "1px grey" }}>
              <p className="title is-5">{title}</p>
              <p className="content">{description}</p>
              <button className="button is-success">Edit</button>
              <button
                onClick={this.handleDelete(_id)}
                className="button is-success"
              >
                Delete
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
  return {
    nothing: "nothing"
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Cards)
```

`deletePost`

```
export const deletePost = (id) => {
    return async dispatch => {
      dispatch({ type: "DELETING_POST_START" })
      try {
        const deletedPost = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts/${id}/delete`)
        dispatch({
          type: "DELETING_POST_SUCCESS",
          data: deletedPost
        })
      } catch(error) {
        dispatch({
          type: "DELETING_POST_FAILURE",
          data: { error: "Something went wrong" }
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ deletePost }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cards)
```

And then call it as a prop:

```
onClick={this.props.deletePost(_id)}
```

Comment: `onClick={this.props.handleDelete(_id)}`. Where am i getting `handleDelete` from props?